# Why was the Force Ghost scene altered in the 2004 DVD version of Return of the Jedi?

Tags: production, star-wars, alternate-version, return-of-the-jedi

In the 2004 DVD edition of *Star Wars Episode VI: Return of the Jedi*, Sebastian Shaw is replaced by Hayden Christensen as Anakin Skywalker's Force Ghost.

But why? The other Force Ghosts appear to be the same age as they were at their time of death, and the same was true for Anakin until the 2004 alteration. So why was this change made?

Comment: Rumor has it that it was done so people familiar with prequel trilogy immediately know who the third guy is.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Because, as per Obi-Wan, that is what Anakin looked like when he died**.

Obi-Wan makes sure to create a distinction between the Jedi Anakin Skywalker and the Sith Darth Vader, going so far as the claim that Darth Vader killed Anakin.

In reality, we know that

> Darth Vader and Anakin Skywalker are the same person

but the creation of this distinction answers your question - Anakin died when he was killed by Darth Vader, and as such his Force Ghost at the end of the film reflects what he looked like when he died.

Comment: Wow, that's a...surprisingly reasonable explanation.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson It's nonsense of course, as the titular *Return of the Jedi* was the return of Anakin Skywalker to the light-side of the Force in my eyes, but I think this is what George Lucas was going for, in all his infinite wisdom.

Comment: I like the spoiler tag for the 30 year old movie :P

Comment: @DavidGrinberg You can never be too careful!

Comment: @DrRDizzle Is that an official explanation of the title? I always thought it was meant to indicate the return of the institution of the Jedi, as the plural and singular forms of the word are the same. In any case, to me Anakin was reborn and Darth Vader died at the end of *Jedi* and therefore having the old Anakin force ghost would also make sense by this logic.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I don't know, I think it's probably just as good as "*bs alterations*". Obi-Wan was twisting the truth and he knew it. That's what he told Luke - *So, what I told you was true... from a certain point of view.* Of course, this answer could be right... from a certain point of view ;)

Comment: @ToddWilcox I honestly don't know. [This question on SciFi.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63906/who-is-the-eponymous-jedi-in-return-of-the-jedi) has several different answers, but I tend to lean towards the one mentioned in my answer here - that the return of Anakin Skywalker is the return of the Jedi mentioned in the films title

Comment: @ToddWilcox I don't think that Anakin really died and was reborn at the end. Anakin was still somewhere behind that mask all along - though it seems Luke was the only person who could sense the presence of Anakin.

Comment: @kasperd This would be supported by the fact that Vader still had enough Anakin in him to finish off the Emperor... but shhhhh, we need to justify Lucas trying to get us to accept Christensen as Anakin/Vader.

Comment: Anakin was killed by Darth Vader? Don't you mean Anakin became Darth Vader, or am I missing something?

Comment: @camden_kid The person Anakin Skywalker was "killed" when he turned into Darth Vader, according to Obi-Wan. It's true, from a certain point of view.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if perhaps you might want to write it like that in your excellent answer.

Comment: "It's nonsense of course, as the titular Return of the Jedi was the return of Anakin Skywalker to the light-side of the Force in my eyes".  Yeah this.  He became "Anakin" again before dying so going back to his old form made no sense.  It was George Lucas meddling.

Answer (score 9):

George Lucas has a history of constantly changing his past works, this is no exception.

Most of the changes are just for the sake of change (under guise of "improving" the older films). However, in cases such as this, it serves to add nothing additional to the movie (unlike improving special effects that were already present in the film).

In essence, George Lucas couldn't resist keeping his grubby hands off the film, leaving it "finished" as it were.

Comment: You aren't getting any love, but you're in the ballpark of the actual reason. Lucas needed SOMETHING to do to the post RotS original trilogy re-release. He had already fixed most of the actual issues up with the remastered re-release about 10 years prior, so the changing of Anakin was one of the handful of things he used to justify selling another recut. If it makes him a buck, he will do it, then go back and figure out how to change canon to justify it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Lucas just came out with a change so he could make more money from that movie.